# docker Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

My docker container was accessing my GPU a few weeks ago (last successful run was Aug 31), but now, coming back to my project, I'm getting the following error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].`

I've tried several variants of re-installing `docker`, and `nvidia-docker2` and `nvidia-container-toolkit` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400476/docker-error-response-from-daemon-could-not-select-device-driver-with-capab) and [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7581#issuecomment-729558589). I've tried restarting the instance before, between, and after the steps above. No luck.

I assume that, since my docker image didn't change, that some sort of CUDA update or similar, in the intervening weeks, broke the connection between the hardware and the docker. But I'm stumped as to what to try next.

Here are a few more details about my setup:

- AWS EC2 g5.4xlarge
- Amazon Linux 2
- NVIDIA A10G
- NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03 Driver Version: 510.47.03 CUDA Version: 11.6
- Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

Running the command below reproduces the error:

`sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.6.0-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi`